# Lollipop (sony experia Z3 compact) - disable mobile data notification

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, notification-icons

I just recently upgraded to lollipop. One thing that is annoying, is with notifications.

Most of the time I have mobile data disabled, because in most places I can connect to wifi (when I need mobile net, I just simply enable it through settings).
But now every time I turn my screen on I see mobile data notification and when I unlock it also in upper left of the screen. I don't see a way to disable it.

Is there a way to do that? Cause I really don't need that (I could really disable all notifications in main screen (that new one, before unlocking).

**Update** OK so managed to disable notifications on lock (in sound & notification - "when device is locked", choosing to not show any notifications). But mobile data notification in upper left corner is still up there all the time..

Comment: Still would like to know a solution to your original answer. Neither hiding all notifications on lock screen nor regularly clearing all notifications is a real solution for me :/

Comment: There's a thread over at XDA: http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-module-xposed-dtn-disabler-t2404404 containing an xposed module to disable this notification, but it also has some alternative, will provide feedback once tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there was a button near notification (when I hover it over) (like a stairs icon or something). Pressing it cleared notification and now it is not appearing, so I hope it wont show it again :).

Comment: That's a "clear all notifications" actually. Not sure if it really solves the core issue, but indeed it's a workaround to remove that notification at a time.